# Getting build error in ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created two classes under the Models folder inside an ASP.NET MVC:-

```
namespace TMS.Models
{

    public class ADIntigration
{
    public static DomainContext GetUserDetails()
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            IPrincipal principal = HttpContext.Current.User;
            WindowsIdentity identity = ((WindowsIdentity)principal.Identity);
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, identity.Name);

            if (principal != null)
            {
                return new DomainContext() {
                    userGuid = user.Guid,
                    DisplayName = user.DisplayName,
                    GivenName = user.GivenName,
                    EmailAddress = user.EmailAddress
                };
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

&

```
namespace TMS.Models
{
    class DomainContext
    {
        public class domainContext
        {
            public Nullable<Guid> userGuid { get; set; }
            public string DisplayName { get; set; }
            public string GivenName { get; set; }
            public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

but I am getting a build error that :-

> Inconsistent accessibility: return type 'project.Models.DomainContext'
>   is less accessible than  method
>   'project.Models.ADIntigration.GetUserDetails()'

So how I can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

If you omit the `public` from `class DomainContext` then it will be seen as `internal class DomainContext` which is less accessible than `public class ADIntigration`.

Therefore you need to change `class DomainContext` to `public class DomainContext`

Answer (score 0):

Change  `class DomainContext` to `public  class DomainContext`

Answer (score 0):

The default [*access modifier*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) of a class is [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx). You should update it to [`public`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yzh058ae.aspx).

Change

```
class DomainContext
```

to

```
public class DomainContext
```